# JavaScript way to convert C# List<string> value?

Tags: c#, angularjs

I have this singleton created in global.asax

```
private void SetAppConfig()
{
    AppConfig.Instance.ClientId = 46;
    AppConfig.Instance.Language = "en";
    AppConfig.Instance.UserId = 7466897;
    AppConfig.Instance.UserName = "RSTEST";
    AppConfig.Instance.SessionId = "XXXX";
    AppConfig.Instance.AppIds = new List<string>(new string[] { "element1", "element2", "element3" });
    AppConfig.Instance.IsValidSession = true;
}
```

Please note **AppConfig.Instance.AppIds** property which is of type `List<string>`.

I need to set this singleton object to its AngularJS constant copy AppConfig before I can inject it into my DataService and my controllers

[image]

Everything works perfect except of this small thing on the screenshot :)

I need the value of this **AppConfig.Instance.AppIds** property converted into JavaScript array format.

**It has to be done on JS side right there the yellow line is.**
instead of getting the C# type name )

**I forgot, whats the syntax ??**

Thanks!

cnorthfield, thanks!

> @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(AppConfig.Instance.AppIds))

the other option that works is, but your shorter ))

> @Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(AppConfig.Instance.AppIds))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Simple solution

Use the [`Html.Raw`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740(v=vs.118).aspx) helper method and JSON encoding it using the [`Json.Encode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.json.encode(v=vs.111).aspx) method like so:

```
@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(AppConfig.Instance.AppIds));
```

### How does it work?

1. The [`Json.Encode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.json.encode(v=vs.111).aspx) method first converts your list to a string that in JSON format.
2. Using [`Html.Raw`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740(v=vs.118).aspx) the markup your JSON string won't be HTML encoded, this means it's ready for your JavaScript to use without any need for further processing!

Comment: @monstro You're welcome, feel free to mark this answer as accepted if you think it will help people in the future.

Comment: sure, it doesnt let to mark it as an answer within first 5 min for some reason )